# RICOH AFICIO SP C242SF: I can't install the network scanner but only USB scanner

Tags: networking, windows-10, usb, scanner

I have installed the printer and scanner via usb and I have copied the local device by changing the port from USB to TCP/IP address, but the network device (the copy of the local device) can only print and not scan. Why?
I give you the screenshots to make you understand better:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the printer and reinstalling via network? I have a c435dn that not only does not like the pcl-5c drivers, but will not work on the network if you install the drivers via USB. The pcl-6 drivers worked fine.

Comment: Yes, in past i have installed directly driver PCL-6 from IP manually but the problem was the same. Only the printer was seen and not the scanner.